# Android: Can't get shared element transition to work with Google Maps Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, transition

I am attempting to get a Google Maps Fragment to persist between two Activities. I don't know how to do the persist part but I definitely want the Map to show up in both activities. To make the shared element transition, I have given the fragments the same transitionName. I have also enabled Window Transitions and I've started Activity B like so:

```
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, map, getString(R.string.map));
    startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

But for the life of me, I can't get this transition to work. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Activity A:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:transitionName="@string/map"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_map_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.gyang.android.MapActivity"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Activity B:

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:transitionName="@string/map"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spacer_between_logo_and_map"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        tools:context="com.example.gyang.android.MapActivity"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you got the working solution for it.

Comment: same issue! Did you got the working solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Well it might be late or there may are better solutions but that's what worked for me:

In Activity A I'm using a ImageView, where I display a small part of the map I want to show on Activity B.

On Activity B I put the `<fragment>` into a LinearLayout for example, where I put the transitionName I wanted to use.

The transition animation is now "Zooming" up my Image and morphes it into the maps fragment.

I hope this may help anybody out there, still searching for a solution.